# cordova hot-code-push plugin security

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm reviewing the [cordova-hot-code-push](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push) cordova plugin.  I want to host my releases on my own server.  Is there a way to use some security to ensure that not just anyone can download the files from the hosted location and still work in conjunction with the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Authentication Headers when manually calling the fetchUpdate() method.

```
var options = {
  'config-file': 'https://example.com/chcp.json',
  'request-headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer("username:password").toString('base64'))
  }
};
chcp.fetchUpdate(updateCallback, options);

function updateCallback(error, data) {
  // do some work
}
```

Is not the most secure method as still anyone who inspects the App Code, will be able to download your code.

But what I personally would be much more concerned about is the ability of someone to "fake update" your app, as a Man in The middle thus being able to completely hijack your App.

!! -> So definately use HTTPS.

Which also cannot completely stop MITMs.

Reference read here:

https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push/wiki/Fetch-update

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication